# pass to a component, via slot, a component that emits events

Tags: vue.js, components, eventemitter, slot

Hi all: I have a modal that I would like the buttons to be passed through slots, each with its own events. The problem is that when I click on the button, the event fires but the parent can't hear it.

```
<template>
 <modal-detail v-if="viewModal" title="Modifica brands" @close="viewModal=false">
        <!-- <template #header><p>ciao bob</p></template> -->
        <template #body>
            sdfgsfgddd
        </template>
        <template #actions>
            <button-cancel buttonText="cancella" @click="$emit('close')"></button-cancel>
            <button-confirm buttonText="conferma" @click="$emit('confirm')"></button-confirm>
        </template>
    </modal-detail>
</template>
```

The problem is thath @close="something" is never called.

Suggestion?

Thanks, all

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using a custom component button. You either need to bind the @click handler to prop callback or use `@click.native` to apply the click handler.

To help debugging events and other issues such as with Vuex in the future, you can use the [Vue browser dev tools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools).

If you install that plugin, and check the events stream you can see what events are being emitted by what. For example, if you haven't correctly set up your click handler with your  custom button then you won't see the event getting emitted.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Why not? Does it not work if you put `@close="viewModal=false"` on the `template #actions` tag?

Comment: Updated my answer. I notice you're using custom buttons. You either need to pass a callback function down as a prop and call it from within the button itself, or you need to bind using the `.native` modifier. Check the Vue dev tools to see if the event is being emitted :)